# Changing the distance an internal link scrolls down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi I've got a nav menu that changes to fixed once scrolled down the page a certain amount of pixels.
Because the menu is fixed, it overlays the top cutting out the header of that section.

I'm looking to affect how far the page moves when using the menu to move to a section on the page, so sort of negatively offset how far the page scrolls down to show all the menu aswell as section header if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: That is usually triggered on a scroll function in a js file I think. You could search for that or post a link to your website and someone could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue and came up with the following solution:

```
<nav class="fixed">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  ...
</nav>

...

<div id="about" class="anchor-helper"></div>
<div class="container-i-actually-want-to-see>
  <!-- your content goes here -->
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
nav {
  height: 50px;
}

.anchor-helper {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px; /* however tall your nav is, you want this to be negative that amount */
}
```

What I like about this solution is that it relies on CSS as much as possible and only uses javascript for smooth scrolling. If someone navigates to `http://your-site.com/example-page#about`, they will get to where you want them to be.